# vue is not showing the data

Tags: javascript, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore

I load data from firestore in an async manner. I can show the data in the log, but vue is just showing the initial value from before the data is loaded.

I try calling the loading method both using beforeMount() and from a click of the button.

I know I'm missing something fundamental - please help to find it.

```
<template>
  <div class="pt-3">
    <v-row class="d-flex justify-center">
      <v-col cols=4>
        <v-text-field
          label="Nyt land"
          outlined v-model="newItem"
          @keyup.enter="addItem"/>
      </v-col>
      <v-col cols=4>
        <v-text-field
          label="Region"
          outlined v-model="newRegion"
          @keyup.enter="addItem"/>
      </v-col>
    </v-row>
    <v-row class="d-flex justify-center">
        <v-col cols=6>
          <v-btn color="primary" @click="addItem">Tilføj land</v-btn>
      </v-col>
    </v-row>
    
    <v-row class="d-flex justify-center">
        <v-col cols=6>
          <v-btn @click="getGeoHierarchy('Geographies',0,0,[])">Fetch Geographies</v-btn>
      </v-col>
    </v-row>
    <v-row>
        {{vGeoData}}
        <v-col>
            <v-card v-for="(geography,id) in vGeoData" :key="id">
                <v-card-title>{{geography[0].name | capitalize }} </v-card-title>
                <v-card-text>  tests</v-card-text>
            </v-card>
        </v-col>
    </v-row>
  </div>
</template>


<script>
import { db } from '../firebase/db'
export default {
    async created(){
        
    },
    beforeMount(){
        this.getGeoHierarchy('Geographies',0,0,[]);
    },
    data() {
        return {
            Geographies:[],
            newItem: "",
            newRegion:"",
            vFirst:true,
            vTopLevel:0,
            vGeoData: [''],
            vToplevelData: [],


        }
    },
    filters: {
        capitalize: function (value) {
            if (!value) return ''
            value = value.toString()
            return value.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + value.slice(1)
        }
    },
    methods:{
        async addItem() {
            if(this.newItem && this.newRegion) {
                var docData = {
                    name: this.newItem,
                    regions : {
                        name: this.newRegion
                    }
                };
                await db.collection("Geographies").add(docData);
                this.newItem ="";
                this.newRegion = "";
            }
        },
        deleteItem(id){
            db.collection("Geographies").doc(id).delete();
        },
        async getGeoHierarchy(vPath,vStep,vCounter,vGeographies){
        
            console.log(vPath)
            const vTempGeo = [];
            await db.collection(vPath)
                .get()
                .then(function(querySnapshot) {
                    querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
                        // doc.data() is never undefined for query doc snapshots
                        const vCollections = doc.data().collections;
                        vTempGeo.push({
                            name: doc.data().name,
                            id: doc.id,
                            collection: vCollections,
                            path: vPath + "/" + doc.id,
                            level: vStep,
                        })
                        return vTempGeo
                    });
                });
                
            //debugger;
            console.table("vGeographies:",vGeographies);
            for(let i=0; i<vTempGeo.length;i++){
                vGeographies.splice(vCounter+i,0,vTempGeo[i]);
                // debugger
            }
            const lGeographies = vGeographies.length;
            for (let i=vStep; i<lGeographies;i++){
                const vCurrent = vGeographies[i];
                //debugger
                if(Array.isArray(vCurrent.collection)){
                    
                    for(let j=0; j < vCurrent.collection.length; j++){
                        await this.getGeoHierarchy(vCurrent.path+"/"+vCurrent.collection[j],vStep+i+j+1,vCounter+1,vGeographies);
                    }
                }
            }
            console.log("this.Geographies",this.Geographies);
            console.table("vGeographies:",vGeographies);
            // debugger
            this.Geographies = vGeographies;
            this.populateGeoData(0);
            return this.Geographies
            
        },
        populateGeoData(vTopLevel) {
            console.log('--populateGeodata','start')
            console.table("this.Geographies:",this.Geographies);
            let vTempArr = [];
            let vTopLevelData = [];
            let vTempGeo = [];
            
            let vFirst = true;
            let vTopLevelCounter = 0;

            
            for(const geography of this.Geographies){
                console.log("geography:", geography)
                const last = (this.Geographies.length-1 == this.Geographies.indexOf(geography))
                // debugger
                if(!vFirst){
                    if(geography.level==vTopLevel){
                        vTempGeo[0] = vTopLevelData
                        vTempGeo[1] = vTempArr;
                        this.vGeoData[vTopLevelCounter] = vTempGeo;
                        vTempGeo = [];
                        vTopLevelData = geography;
                        vTempArr = [];
                        vTopLevelCounter++;
                    }
                    else {
                        vTempArr.push(geography);
                    }
                }
                else {
                    if(geography.level == vTopLevel){
                        vTopLevelData = geography;
                        vFirst = false
                    }
                    else{
                        console.log("populateGeoData", "First is not toplevel")
                        vTempArr.push(geography)
                    }
                }
                if(last){
                    if(geography.level == vTopLevel){
                        vTempGeo[0] = vTopLevelData
                        vTempGeo[1] = vTempArr;
                        this.vGeoData[vTopLevelCounter] = vTempGeo;
                    }
                    else {
                        vTempArr.push(geography)
                        this.vGeoData[vTopLevelCounter] = vTempGeo;
                    }
                }
               
            }
           
            console.table("vGeoData:",this.vGeoData)
            console.log('--populateGeodata','end')
            return this.vGeoData;
        }
    },
    firestore: {
        Geographies: db.collection("Geographies")
    },
    mounted(){
        
    },
    watch:{
    }
}
</script>
<style lang="stylus">
    .grape {

    }
</style>
```

THANKS

Comment: regarding the initial render issue, `vGeoData` is an array with an empty string as first item, but you are using it in your template like `{{vGeoData}}` which is correct, because it will return and empty string

Comment: Yes, I know. But the 'parseGeoData()' function should update it.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `async mounted` and export your data loading logic there. Then, thanks to the help of vue devtools, you could inspect the state of your app. It should help you find out where the bug comes from.

Comment: Thanks, kissu. It shows vGeoData is an array with length 2, but an empty array is shown in the template

Comment: So weird. If I print Geographies before vGeoData it reads vGeodata, if not vGeoData is empty?

Comment: Are you sure your method `populateGeoData` do properly handle your data? Try to check it's value locally and then update your data (no need to return). What happens if you write `<pre>{{ vGeoData }}</pre>` ? Do you have a screenshot of your data in the devtools?

Comment: @BispensGipsGebis not sure what is happening exactly here but I see that `Geographies: db.collection("Geographies")` contains `Geographies` and that it is also the name of your data `Geographies:[],` so there is maybe also a conflict. You think that you actually are just printing some variables but instead, are running a fetch on Firebase. Try maybe renaming some variables.

Comment: I will try posting a screenshot tonight, Kissu. Ref. changing variables. “Geographies” is the name of the collection in firestore, sonI can’t change that. According to online examples, this is the way to load a collection into vue, but I can try changing names. Not sure it will help much